# An invertible linear map over C has a square root (Linear Algebra Done Right 8.33)

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

$T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is a complex finite-dim linear operator. 8.33 proves that if $T$ is invertible, it must have a square root.

It shows that $T |_{G(\lambda_i, T)} = \lambda_i (I + \frac{N_i}{\lambda_i})$ has a square root, where $N_i \in \mathcal{L}(G(\lambda_i, T))$ is a nilpotent, $G(\lambda_i, T)$ is generalized eigenvectors space and $\{ \lambda_i \}$ is a set of distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

Finally, the proof finishes by saying that the operator $Rv = R_1 u_1 + ... + R_m u_m$, where $R_i = \sqrt{T |_{G(\lambda_i, T)}} = \sqrt{\lambda_i (I + \frac{N_i}{\lambda_i})}$, is indeed the square root of $T$ and $u_i \in G(\lambda_i, T)$.

I'm having trouble verifying this.

By applying $R$ expansion to the right side I get

$R_1 (R_1 u_1 + ... R_m u_m) + ... + R_m(R_1 u_1 + ... + R_m u_m) = R_1^2u_1 + ... + R_m^2u_m + R_1(R_2u_2 + ... + R_m u_m) + ... + R_m(R_1 u_1 + ... + R_{m-1} 
u_{m-1})$

$R^2_i u_i = \lambda_i (I + \frac{N_i}{\lambda_i}) u_i = T|_{G(\lambda_i, T)} u_i$, is what I need, but the rest of the terms are excessive.

So I need to show that $R_1(R_2u_2 + ... + R_m u_m) + ... + R_m(R_1 u_1 + ... + R_{m-1} u_{m-1}) = 0$.

**Q1)** $R_i$ is defined on the elements of $G(\lambda_i, T)$, but in the equation above, $R_1$, for instance, needs to map an element of $G(\lambda_2, T) + ... + G(\lambda_m, T)$. It's probably going to map to $0$, but I'm confused how a linear map restricted to $G(\lambda_i, T)$ is to deal with elements outside this set.

**Q2)** If $R_i u_j \neq 0$ for $i\neq j$, then what is it equal to?

**Edit**: I realized I applied $R$ incorrectly. Applying it correctly makes the verification simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the Jordan normalform of a matrix? This states that any complex (square) matrix $T$ can be written as $ T = S \Lambda S^{-1}  $, where $\Lambda$ is block diagonal and $S$ consists of the (generalized) eigenvectors of $T$. Hence changing the basis to $S$, the matrix $T$ will be block diagonal. This means that the vector space $V$ can be written as $V = \oplus_{i=1}^m V_i $, where $V_i$'s are invariant under the action of $T$. Thus for any $u\in V$
$$ Tu = T_1 u_1 + T_2 u_2 + \ldots + T_m u_m  $$
holds,
where $T_i T_j = T_jT_i = 0$ for $i\neq j$. This also implies that, due to the definition of the $R_j$s, $R_i R_j = R_j R_i = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: The proof given in Linear Algebra Done Right that every invertible operator (on a finite-dimensional complex vector space) has a square root does not use the Jordan form. The hard part of the Jordan form is unnecessary for this proof of this theorem.

Comment: You need the part that $V$ can be written as a sum of $T$-invariant subspaces.

Comment: What is needed here is that $V$ is the direct sum of subspaces, each of which is $T$-invariant, and on each of which $T - \lambda I$ is nilpotent for some number $\lambda$. This is content of Theorem 8.21 in Linear Algebra Done Right, and it does not require Jordan form. The hard part of Jordan form, which is not needed here, is the description of nilpotent operators as having a matrix representation with 1's and 0's just above the diagonal and 0's everywhere else.

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with that book, but the 0s and 1s part is basically just one step from examining the sequence $Ker (T-\lambda I)^m$ and $Im( T-\lambda I)^m$.